Python-Barcode Quality
i have made python program to make barcode and write on it by using python-barcode,PIL library now i use PIL to resize image then write on it example:
with image.open("namr"+".png") as img:
 img=img.resize((143,76),PIL.Image.LANCZOS)
img.save(file="file.png")

now i want the barcode to be in sticker 3.8×2 cm but when i resize barcode it pixelated i want it to be clear to be printed and scanned to be on products
i tried using Image.LANCZOS but didnt work

also i want the barcode able to be read easily by scanner

Better set desired module_width and height as options in the Writer in python-barcode.

i want the quality to be good without pixelating i tried that but problem it doesnt  a good solution

Please add your input image, your current output image and your expected output image so that your question is a proper [mcve]. That will also improve your chances of getting an answer. Thank you.
